# Getting errors due to babel version conflict such that it is not compatible with istantbul to check code coverage

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have used ES6 syntax on my Nodejs project with the help of babel. But, for some reason while trying to test it on, it doesn't quite work.

```
app.js

import express from 'express';
import { readdir } from 'fs';

const app = express();

module.exports = app;
```

*.test.js

```
import {app} from '../app';

describe('OTP test', function () {

    it('should get OTP for unregistered user', function (done) {
}
}
```

Error:

```
import {app} from '../app';
           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Error : When using import app from '../app';

import app from '../app';
       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Expected Result: babel should have solved the issue.

Comment: It looks like a problem with paths, can you show directory structure, .babelrc and how you run this test?

Comment: It was a babel version issue. Apparently, Babel version 7 + was required.